# Golang backend using gin to create routes

Tags: go, http, backend

First of all, i want apologise cause i'm learning english so my english is not so good but i wish you can understand my question :)
I don't know why but always when i build my application to linux and push to a docker container and i run this application, i can't use the routes in my browser, but always when i create a single route in net/http i can run this route in my browser.
I write my code on windows system and i need to deploy my application in a docker to push to a cloud service to run my routes
i don't know if the error is in the gin but is very weird

Here is an example of routes

```
package routes

import (
    "ahboa/src/controllers"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

    swaggerfiles "github.com/swaggo/files"
    ginSwagger "github.com/swaggo/gin-swagger"
)

func HandleRequests() {
    router := gin.Default()
    gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
    router.SetTrustedProxies(nil)

    config := cors.DefaultConfig()
    config.AllowOrigins = []string{"*"}

    router.Use(cors.New(config))

    main := router.Group("api/")
    {
        login := main.Group("login")
        {
            login.POST("/", controllers.LoginByEmail)
        }
        users := main.Group("users")
        {
            users.GET("/", controllers.GetAllUsers)
            users.GET("/:id", controllers.GetUsersByID)
            users.POST("/", controllers.CreateUsers)
            users.PUT("/:id", controllers.UpdateUsers)
            users.DELETE("/:id", controllers.DeleteUsers)
        }
        swagger := main.Group("swagger")
        {
            swagger.GET("/*any", ginSwagger.WrapHandler(swaggerfiles.Handler))
        }
        router.Run(fmt.Sprint(":", "8080"))
    }
}
```

here is an example of my model

```
func GetAllUsers() ([]entities.Users, error) {
    var Users []entities.Users
    result := database.Table("users").Model(&Users).Find(&Users)
    return Users, result.Error
}
```

here is an example of my controller

```
func GetAllUsers(ctx *gin.Context) {
    Users, err := models.GetAllUsers()
    if err != nil {
        httputil.NewError(ctx, http.StatusBadRequest, err)
        return
    }
    ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, Users)
}
```

i have success when i create a single request using net/http but i don't receive this success when i put the code when i use gin

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the issue is related to the configuration of your Linux environment, specifically the ports that your application is listening on.
You are trying to run your application on port 8080 by

router.Run(fmt.Sprint(":", "8080"))

It's possible that this port is being blocked by a firewall or some other configuration on the Linux system. You can check the status of the firewall by running the command systemctl status firewalld . If the firewall is active, you can try adding a rule to allow incoming traffic on port 8080 using the command firewall-cmd --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent and then reload the firewall using the command firewall-cmd --reload.

Also another point that it may be is related to the CORS(Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) headers not being set correctly, specifically by this line

config.AllowOrigins = []string{"*"}

that allow all origin to your server, but it is better to limit this to only the urls that you want to allow request to, and maybe you also need to add headers or methods to the CORS configuration.

This is a place to start troubleshoot your problem. But without more information about your exact environment and setup it's hard to give you a more specific answer.